# Get detailed report Why website is detected as phishing attempt

Tags: wordpress, devops, phishing

One of the apps that I'm working on recently received phishing detection by BitDefender service. I wonder, what may the cause such a scenario?

It uses up to date version of the WordPress.

Here is the report:

https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/7399557ed6efe17e14c6248740d1a17094ec87b63646123b56a148a9ae1e353c/detection

I've already written to BitDefender for an extra explanation but didn't receive any info yet.

This site tells me that from their perspective something is not OK:

https://zulu.zscaler.com/submission/e9aa7749-b684-467a-be17-fe874eaf6514

Could that be the 302 redirect from non-secure to secure version of the website that causes the issue? Should I switch to 301 instead?

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: Maybe you have an old plug-in, or some bad stuff hidden in your wp installation. Usually with modification dates, you can find the bad files. but a fresh installation and comparing file per file the differences, gives you better hints. WP is popular, so also sophisticated attack to WP.

Comment: Install Wordfence and run a full scan to check for malware.

Comment: I've tried both of it - it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've already resolved the issue. In fact, someone reported us (probably competitor) and the default strategy in such case is to mark page us phishing. For de-listing, I've contacted BitDefender directly and they did manual check and delisting after 3-4 days.

Thanks, everyone for your effort!